# Resolve-DnsName inside Test-Connection

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I was wondering how I could return the `Resolve-DnsName` output from my `Test-Connection` script and add it to the CSV I created.

I like to capture the Name, Type, TTL, Section from that please.

Only invoke the `Resolve-DnsName` when the ping is not successful.

```
$servers = Get-Content "servers.txt"
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
    $result = Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($result)
    {
        $status.Results = "Up"
        $status.IP =  ($result.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString
    }
    else
    {
        $status.Results = "Down"
        $status.IP = "N/A"
        $status.DNS = if (-not(Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
        {
            Write-Output -Verbose "$server -- Not Resolving"
        }
        else
        {
            "$server resolving"
        }
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus

    $collection += $serverStatus
}
$collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath .\ServerStatus3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

but nothing new is added to the CSV.

Comment: Don't assume. Try. If it fails: come back and show what you tried as well as the results you got.

Comment: If nothing is added I'd suspect that the name does resolve. Add an `else` branch to that statement to make sure: `$status.DNS = if (...) {...} else {"$server resolving"}`

Comment: I tried that, nothing is written out at all. ANy other suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran into a PowerShell gotcha. PowerShell determines the columns displayed in tabular/CSV output from the first object processed. If that object doesn't have a property `DNS` that column won't be shown in the output, even if other objects in the list do have it. If other objects don't have properties that were present in the first object they will be displayed as empty values.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $a = (New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{'a'=1; 'b'=2}),
>> (New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{'a'=3; 'b'=4; 'c'=5}),
>> (New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{'b'=6; 'c'=7})
>>
PS C:\> $a | Format-Table -AutoSize

a b
- -
1 2
3 4
  6

PS C:\> $a[1..2] | Format-Table -AutoSize

c b a
- - -
5 4 3
7 6
```

If you want to generate tabular output *always* create your objects uniformly with the same set of properties. Choosing sensible defaults even allows you to reduce your total codebase.

```
$collection = foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $status = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'ServerName' = $server
    'TimeStamp'  = Get-Date -f s
    'Results'    = 'Down'
    'IP'         = 'N/A'
    'HasDNS'     = [bool](Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -EA SilentlyContinue)
  }

  $result = Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -EA SilentlyContinue

  if ($result) {
    $status.Results = 'Up'
    $status.IP      =  ($result.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString
  }

  $status
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. General question, if I wanted to loop thru the result and get for example the Type, TTL and section? Is that documented somehow how to retrieve those?