# Resolve DNS address with more than one IP

Tags: powershell, csv, dns, ip

I'm currently trying to get a CSV file that shows the IP address of domains and the domain itself. I would do this manually but I'm testing close to 1K domains.

This is my current code:

```
$Domains = Get-Content "X:\User\URLs.txt"
$collection = $()

foreach($Domain in $Domains)
   {
    Write-Host "Testing $Domain"
    $status = @{ "Domain" = $Domain}
    $result = [system.net.dns]::GetHostAddresses($Domain)

    if($result)
    {
        $status.Results = "UP"
        $status.IP = [system.net.dns]::GetHostAddresses($Domain).IPAddressToString
        Write-Host "GOOD"        
    }#END If

    else
    {
        $status.Results = "Down"
        $status.IP = "N/A"
        $status.DNS = if (-not(Resolve-DnsName -Name $Domain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
        {
         Write-Output -Verbose "$Domain -- Not Resolving"
        }#END inner if

        else
        {
        "$Domain resolving"
        }#END inner else

    }#END else

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable domainStatus
    $collection += $domainStatus

}#END forEach
$collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "X:\User\DomainList.csv" -Append -Force
```

The issue I am having is that some domains have more than 1 IP address and when I open the CSV file, I get a  `System.Object[]` for the domains with more than 1 IP. For the most part I used [Resolve-DnsName inside Test-Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606073/resolve-dnsname-inside-test-connection) to create this code, but again, the issue is when there's more than 1 IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV Don't understand Array's Objects, only plain text.

You can Join the IP's (If more then one) using commas (or any other character) just before the `Export-CSV` cmdlet, like this:

```
$Collection | Select Domain,@{N="IP";E={$_.IP -join ','} },Results |
Export-Csv -LiteralPath "X:\User\DomainList.csv" -Append -Force
```

Another Option is to add another row for each IP, but you need to modify your code a little:

```
$Domains = 'google.com','microsoft.com' 
$Collection = @()

foreach ($Domain in $Domains)
{
    Write-Host "Testing $Domain"

    Try {

        foreach ($IP in [system.net.dns]::GetHostAddresses($Domain).IPAddressToString)
        {
        $Row = "" | Select Domain,IP,Status
        $Row.Domain = $Domain
        $Row.IP = $IP
        $Row.Status = "UP"
        $Collection += $Row
        }
    }

    Catch 
    {
        $Row = "" | Select Domain,IP,Status
        $Row.Domain = $Domain
        $Row.Status = "DOWN"
        $Collection += $Row
    }
}

$Collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "X:\User\DomainList.csv" -Append -Force
```